# Búsqueda Binaria Recursiva en una Matriz en Python

Tags: python, numpy

actualmente tengo de tarea hacer una función que haga una búsqueda binaria recursiva en una matriz y que esta retorne la posición del número buscado, todos los tutoriales que vi tienen como ejemplo la búsqueda en un vector, así que estoy perdido en cuanto a cómo aplicarlo a una matriz, pensé que tal vez podría hacer dos funciones, una que haga la búsqueda en un vector y otra que haga la busqueda en cada una de las filas de la matriz usando la función anterior, pero no sé cómo hacer esta segunda función ya que debe ser recursiva, ¿podrían ayudarme?

```py
import numpy as np

def busquedaEnArreglo(arreglo, numBuscado, primero, ultimo):
    if primero > ultimo:
        return None
    else:
        medio = (ultimo + primero) // 2
        if arreglo[medio] == numBuscado:
            return arreglo [medio]
        elif numBuscado < arreglo[medio]:
            return busquedaEnArreglo(arreglo,numBuscado, primero, medio-1)
        else:
            return busquedaEnArreglo(arreglo, numBuscado, medio + 1, ultimo)


matriz= np.array ([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]])

def busquedaEnMatriz (matriz, num):
 
???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar en la matriz tenemos que convertir el índice a las coordenadas correspondientes. Por ejemplo en una matriz de `3x3` los índices serían estos:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Para hallar la coordenada `y` basta con dividir el índice por el ancho la matriz. Y para hallar la coordenada `x` basta con calcular el resto de la división entre el índice y el ancho de la matriz:

```py
y = indice // len(matriz[0])
x = indice % len(matriz[0])
```

Entonces la función `busquedaEnMatriz` quedaría así:

```py
def busquedaEnMatriz(matriz, numBuscado, primero, ultimo):
    if primero > ultimo:
        return None
    else:
        medio = (ultimo + primero) // 2
        #Hallamos la coordenada y correspondiente al índice medio
        y = medio // len(matriz[0])
        #Lo mismo para la coordenada x
        x = medio % len(matriz[0])
        if matriz[y][x] == numBuscado:
            return matriz[y][X]
        elif numBuscado < matriz[y][x]:
            return busquedaEnMatriz(matriz, numBuscado, primero, medio-1)
        else:
            return busquedaEnMatriz(matriz, numBuscado, medio + 1, ultimo)

matriz = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]

print(busquedaEnMatriz(matriz, 10, 0, 15))
```

Comment: @Fedex07501 ¡Ya veo, muchas gracias! En serio.